# Intellij highlight file in Project Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

In Eclipse, one can choose a File in Editor, right click and hight-light the file in Project Explorer. That will expand the tree, and one can see the file highlighted. 
I'm wondering how one can accomplish the same in Intellij IDEA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a shortcut: <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> then select `1.Project View`.

Or you can press `Scroll from Source` button:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're a fan of **keyboard shortcuts** like me, you can also assign one via `Settings - Keymap`

[image]

Adding to Ruslan answer, you can also decide to automate the process and keep the `Project ToolWindow` always in sync with the currently opened editor.

Just tick the `Autoscroll *` menu items.

[image]

Comment: In Android Studio the option (instead of `Autoscroll to Source`) is called `Always Select Opened File`